# Checking a radio button to reset a dropdown box using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown and a radio button beside it. When an item is selected in the dropdown
and a user clicks on the radio button, I will like the dropdown to reset itself and have
"Select Number" as the default value.
How can i acheive that?

```
    <div class="selection">
        <label for="accountNumber" class="lbl">@T("Customer Account:")</label>
        <select id="accountNumber"   class="sel" name="accountNumber" ng-model="vm.defaultValue"  
                ng-options="item for item in vm.retrieveAliasName">                              
            <option value="">Select Account</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="acctsAll" class="all">
        <input type="radio" id="AllAccounts" /><span class="lbl">("All")</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Select Number" or "Select Account"?

Comment: Sorry select account

Comment: Check out @Korte'as answer. If it doesn't meet your needs give us some feedback and I'try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to assign your input of type radio a model via `ng-model` directive. Then you have to check wether this model value matches the "All" value and clear default value of your `vm.defaultValue`.

Moreover if I get it right you need to clear and disable the select input when "All" radio is selected, but you might need an other radio which allows user to choose an option from select input. Based on that I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01t5h7vd/) to help you out.

Notice the following parts:

```
<input ng-change="vm.clearDefaultValue()" ng-model="vm.areAllSelected" type="radio" id="AllAccounts" ng-value="true" />
```

and controller function:

```
this.clearDefaultValue = function() {
    this.defaultValue = null;
}
```